# Have problem with openvpn

Tags: openvpn, twitter

I have a problem!
I config OpenVPN on my personal server and when I use it from my PC I can't connect to twitter or facebook! but my IP changes to server IP and everything is ok. Also in my mobile, i can use twitter and anything! this problem just happen on my PC!
Plz, help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you ping `8.8.8.8` when connected to the VPN?

Comment: @AndroidDev yes I can. But changing the DNS on OpenVPN config, I'm not using OpenSSL DNS's. I use of Norton DNS! Also, i have the problem with OpenSSL!